# Control torque to a Reaction wheel that compensates for friction - need help understanding a working code

Tags: attitude, attitude-determination-and-control, reaction-wheel, flight-control, torque

Reaction wheel in a s/c is driven by controller torque. However, since there is friction torque in RW, less than the reqd momentum change is achieved. Hence the control torque must be increased by friction value to drive the wheel as reqd.

The following MATLAB/OCATVE code is capable of estimating friction and generating net commanded control torque to reaction wheel that compensates for friction by giving additional torque to reqd controller torque.

This code works, but I am unable to understand what is the underlying derivation for the equations in the implemented code. Pls help.

**CODE STARTS:**

```
Tc = 0.1; % Controller Torque for wheel (Nm)
Tf = -0.04; % Friction Tq
J = 0.1 ; % RW inertia (kgm^2)
wnom = 500; %nominal RW speed in RPM

wact=wnom; % actual RW speed in RPM
Hp=0;
Ts= 0.04; %sampling time (sec)
K = 1/2;
i=4; 
j=0;

for t=0:Ts/4:100 % wheel speed integration at Ts/4 sec

    if i==4 % tq to wheel is computed every Ts seconds
        i=0;
    T1 = Tc + Tc*Ts*K + Hp;
    Hp = Hp + Tc*Ts*K;

    Tcmd = T1 + K*J*(2*pi/60)*(wnom-wact);
    end

    i=i+1;
    wact = wact + (Tcmd+Tf)*(Ts/4)/J/2/pi*60;

    j=j+1;
    w(j)=wact;
    Tp(j)= Tcmd;
end
```

For insatnce, for these values the Tcmd is 0.14
Changing the value of K changed the settling time of the Tcmd to reach the fina value of 0.14Nm.

Comment: yea.. I got it from somewhere. But this code is whole and can be run standalone, so I guess context is not reqd. As commented the control tq from s/c attitude controller is Tc (after conversion to wheel frame). This code augments the Tc such that it had additional friction tq in it. The code estimates the friction tq and adds to the control tq. I didnt understand the friction estimation part.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best way to invite people to help, but okay.

Comment: IG123 It looks like the torque due to friction is constant at 0.04 so now I'm not sure what you are asking.